# How do I tell LLVM to insert my InlineAsm into the executable without ANY modications?

Tags: binary, x86, clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

> How do I tell LLVM to inject my InlineAsm into the executable without ANY modications?

I've a sequence of `InlineAsm`'s within my LLVM `ModulePass`, that I want to be certain gets inserted into the particular function without any modifications, like optimization, reordering etc.

The `InlineAsm`'s look like this:

```
Builder.CreateCall(InlineAsm::get(VoidFunTy, std::string(".cstart_") + Id + std::string(":"), "", true));
```

Basically, the `llc` compiler is in charge of determining the effect of these `InlineAsm`'s, and normally it just translates them to assembler syntax in the `.s` output file.

Does the `hasSideEffets` argument instruct LLVM to insert the instructions verbatim into the function, or how am I certain that the instructions are inserted without modifications of any sort?

If possible, please link to documentation, since the details are important for the application at hand.